# Set identities - prove equivalence of equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

For a practice question, I'm asked to prove the equivalence of:

$(Y - X) \cap (Z - X)$ and $(Y \cap Z) \cap X^C$

I made some progress on the question, but I'm stuck and not sure what to do next. I can't use the distributivity rule because the signs are all intersection symbols. I'd appreciate some hints or help.

1. $(Y - X) \cap (Z - X)$
2. $(Y \cap X^C) \cap (Z - X)$ by Difference Equivalence
3. $(Y \cap X^C) \cap (Z \cap X^C)$ by Difference Equivalence

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intersection is commutative and associative. Hence,

$$
(Y \cap X^C) \cap (Z \cap X^C) = 
(Y \cap Z) \cap (X^C \cap X^C) = 
(Y \cap Z) \cap X^C 
$$

Comment: Hi! I don't really understand the associative part. Like after communativity, I get (Y ∩ X^C) ∩ (X^C ∩ Z) but I don't get how that would format to follow the (A ∩ B) ∩ C = A ∩ (B ∩ C) rule. I just don't understand how to get the 2nd step.

Comment: $(A \cap C) \cap (B \cap C) = A \cap (C \cap B) \cap C = A \cap (B \cap C) \cap C = (A \cap B) \cap (C \cap C) = (A \cap B) \cap C$. Or if you prefer, $(A \cap C) \cap (B \cap C) = A \cap (C \cap (B \cap C)) = A \cap ((C \cap B) \cap C) = \cdots$

Comment: To the proposer: For any 4 statements $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4$ we have $U\iff V\iff W, $ where $U$ is $(S_1\land S_2\land S_3\land S_4)$ and $V$ is $((S_1\land S_2)\land (S_3\land S_4))$ and $W$ is $((S_1\land S_3)\land (S_2\land S_4)). $...Now for each $i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$ let $A_i$ be a set and let $S_i$ be $p\in A_i.$  Then for any $p$ we have $p\in  (A_1\cap A_2)\cap (A_3\cap A_4)\iff V$ and we have  $p\in (A_1\cap A_3)\cap (A_2\cap A_4)\iff W.$